# Query in oracle to fetch multiple records from one table & enter into other

Tags: oracle

My requirement is to write a query in oracle
"which fetch userids from users table & insert into USERQueries table"

USERS

```
USERID GPID GROUP
1682   1026   IBMSDL2S
1882   1028   IBMSDL2S
1573   1029   IBMSDL2S
1342   1124   IBMSDL2S
1976   2576   IBMSDL2S
1883   2575   IBMSDL2S
1854   2574   IBMSDL2S
2222   2573   IBMSDL2S
2207   2572   IBMSDL2S
```

USERQueries

```
APP  CLAUSENAME           USERID DEFAULTQUERYID OWNER
SR   Assgined_SRs_To_Me   1249   545            MAXADMIN
SR   Assgined_SRs_To_Me   1682   543            MAXADMIN
```

I am able to insert one userid as below

```
insert into  USERSQUERIES  
(APP,CLAUSENAME,USERID,DEFAULTQUERYID,OWNER)   
values   
('SR','Assgined_SRs_To_Me',(select userid from USERS where  groupname='IBMSDL2S' and userid='1249
),DEFAULTQUERYSEQ.NEXTVAL,'MAXADMIN')
```

but didn't understand how it will work for all userids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd write a `SELECT` statement that fetches data you're interested in, and then use it in `INSERT` statement. Have a look at the following example:

Test case first:

```
SQL> create table users as
  2  select 1682 userid, 1026 gpid, 'IBMSDL25' groupname from dual union all
  3  select 1882 userid, 1028 gpid, 'IBMSDL25' groupname from dual union all
  4  select 2222 userid, 2222 gpid, 'XXXXXX25' groupname from dual;            --> will NOT be inserted

Table created.

SQL> create table usersqueries (app varchar2(2),
  2  clausename varchar2(20), userid number, defaultqueryid number, owner
  3  varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> create sequence defaultqueryseq;

Sequence created.

SQL>
```

Testing: starting at line #3 is the `SELECT` statement I mentioned previously.

```
SQL> insert into usersqueries
  2    (app, clausename, userid, defaultqueryid, owner)
  3    select 'SR',
  4           'Assigned_SRs_to_me',
  5           u.userid,
  6           defaultqueryseq.nextval,
  7           'MAXADMIN'
  8    from users u
  9    where u.groupname = 'IBMSDL25';

2 rows created.

SQL> select * From usersqueries;

AP CLAUSENAME               USERID DEFAULTQUERYID OWNER
-- -------------------- ---------- -------------- --------------------
SR Assigned_SRs_to_me         1682              1 MAXADMIN
SR Assigned_SRs_to_me         1882              2 MAXADMIN

SQL>
```

Comment: thnks liitlefoot.